# Need help updating database row with values from HTML form

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've got an admin area where the admins can set the level of repair and it shows on a progress bar in the users area. I have it all working apart from updating the mySQL database to the value submitted.

My database has a table called 'users' and fields 'UserID', 'Username', 'Password', 'progress', 'admin'.

Here is the code I'm using to try and make the magic happen:

```
<?php
$query="SELECT * FROM users";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_numrows($result);

?>
<form id="chooseuseredit" method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
<select name="ChooseUser">
<?php
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

$f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"UserID");
$f2=mysql_result($result,$i,"Username");
$f3=mysql_result($result,$i,"progress");
$f4=mysql_result($result,$i,"admin");
?>

<option value="<?php echo $f1; ?>"><?php echo $f2; ?></option>

<?php
$i++;
}
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="chooseSubmit" id="chooseSubmit" value="Choose User" />
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['chooseSubmit']) )
{
  $varID = $_POST['ChooseUser'];
  $errorMessage = "Jesus Christ Benton, Choose a User!!";

?>
<br>
<p><strong>Editing UserID: <?php echo "$varID"; ?></strong></p>
<p>Progress:<br>
<form name="edituserform" method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
<select name="editinguser">
<option value="0">Phone Not Recieved</option>
<option value="20">Phone Recieved</option>
<option value="40">Parts Recieved</option>
<option value="60">Repair Started</option>
<option value="80">Repair Finished</option>
<option value="100">Posted Back</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="edituserid" id="edituserid" value="<?php echo "$varID"; ?>" />
<input type="submit" name="edituser" id="edituser" value="Edit" />
</form>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['edituser'])){

    $add = $_POST['edituser'];
    $varIDe = $_POST['edituserid'];
    $errorMessage = "Jesus Christ Benton, Choose a User!!";
    $query1 = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET progress = $add WHERE UserID = $varIDe");
    mysql_query($query1) or die("Cannot update");

echo $add;
echo $varIDe;

    }
    ?>

<?php
}
?>
```

I'm not sure if the variables are working or not, or if it's the way I've used the submit button before? Its got me a little stumped.

Comment: Please make sure you read this regarding [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: @Oliver $_POST['edituser'] is the submit button, I think it should be $_POST['editinguser'], just saying – nine7ySix 10 mins ago

Comment: @Oliver :O Why did you change accepted answer?

Comment: sorry, i hadn't realised i had done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're query should be

```
$query1 = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET progress = '$add' WHERE UserID = $varIDe");
```

Don't forget the quotes

and it would be best to change your

`mysql_query($query1) or die("Cannot update");`

to `mysql_query($query1) or die("MySQL ERROR: ".mysql_error());`

to get it to display errors

## edit

Found a few errors

`mysql_numrows` should be `mysql_num_rows`

and **major error**

```
$query1 = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET progress = $add WHERE UserID = $varIDe");
```

is running a query, change it to

```
$query1 = "UPDATE users SET progress = '".$add."' WHERE UserID = '".$varIDe."'";
```

Comment: im still not getting errors and cant get it to work, heres a link to the whole page: http://goo.gl/q5lgS

Comment: hmm, still cant get it to update the database. I've tried everything everyone has suggested and it doesn't seem to want to play ball!

Comment: @Oliver Whysall Change `mysql_query($query1) or die("Cannot update");` to `mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());` and see post the error

Comment: changed all of that and heres the code again, still doesn't want to do anything! http://goo.gl/q5lgS

Comment: i dont get an error, it just goes back to the first part asking to choose a user, try logging in at http://youriphonerepair.x10.mx/postinprogress with username as demo and password as 7575

Comment: @OliverWhysall I can log in, but I don't see what you're seeing

Comment: do you not see the choose user then the other list box?

Comment: make sure its the 7575 password not the 1234

Comment: I only see Repair Area Hello demo. Your your phone is currently 20% repaired.

Comment: sorry i missed off /admin.php at the end of it

Comment: @OliverWhysall Haha, I think I got it. The `UPDATE` is inside the `if(isset($_POST['chooseSubmit']) )
{`, and since `$_POST['chooseSubmit']` doesn't exist after you submit a new form, it doesn't get past this `if`. An easy workaround would be to change it to `if(isset($_POST['chooseSubmit']) || isset($_POST['edituser']) )` or just make a new `if`. If this works, don't forget to accept this answer :)

Comment: thank you so much! i knew it would be something dead small! i've spent too long looking at that script!

Answer (score 0):

I think your getting the wrong variable

```
if(isset($_POST['edituser'])){
  $add = $_POST['edituser']; // this is a button
```

should be :

```
if(isset($_POST['editinguser'])){
  $add = $_POST['editinguser']; // this is a select list
```

### But please read the following about [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't noticed that!

Comment: This is still incorrect -> `if(isset($_POST['edituser'])){` this is a button ?!?!

Answer (score 0):

When something's going wrong, with respect to query, you better debugging, adding one: `or die ( mysql_error ( ) ) ;` and then the error message is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query1 = mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `progress` = '".$add."' WHERE UserID = '".$varIDe."'");
if(mysql_query($query1))
{
//DO SOME ACTION
}
else
{
die(mysql_error());
}
```